# Regex in Python to find words that follow pattern: vowel, consonant, vowel, consonant

Tags: python, regex

Trying to learn Regex in Python to find words that have consecutive vowel-consonant or consonant-vowel combinations.  How would I do this in regex?  If it can't be done in Regex, is there an efficient way of doing this in Python?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use a regular expression like this:

```
r"([aeiou][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz])+"
```

for matching vowel followed by consonant and:

```
r"([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz][aeiou])+"
```

for matching consonant followed by vowel.  For reference, the + means it will match the largest repetition of this pattern that it can find.  For example, applying the first pattern to "ababab" would return the whole string, rather than single occurences of "ab".

If you want to match one or more vowels followed by one or more consonants it might look like this:

```
r"([aeiou]+[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]+)+"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I find words that have the MOST consecutive vowel-consonant matching sequences?

Comment: Store the length of the match when you find it. For future reference, you should try not to change the question like this after asking it.

Comment: @katrielalex - while unfortunate, it is very common for the initial answers to help clarify the issue for the poster, so the question will evolve and morph a bit in response. On parsing questions, I've had this back-and-forth take dozens of steps - see http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=25288&start=80&sid=466b3473819c36063b68f10d580a4e7c

Answer (score 3):

```
^(([aeiou][^aeiou])+|([^aeiou][aeiou])+)$
```

---

```
>>> import re
>>> consec_re = re.compile(r'^(([aeiou][^aeiou])+|([^aeiou][aeiou])+)$')
>>> consec_re.match('bale')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01DBD1D0>
>>> consec_re.match('bail')
>>>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when there are uneven vowels/consonants. `consec_re.match('hiben')` fails for instance.

Comment: -1: This matches any non-vowels rather than consonants. For example, ``consec_re.match('ba7e')`` returns a match.

Comment: This doesn't actually work.  How do I find words that have the MOST consecutive vowel-consonant matching sequences?

Comment: @Blair - if you're expecting your input to contain non-words, then yes, it'd be better to hard code the consonants. If you're matching against individual word strings, however, then it would work fine.

Comment: @Parseltongue: If you wanted to find the most, you should have stated that in your question...

Comment: @Josh: As far as the OP seems to specify, that's intentional.

Comment: @Amber, I don't believe that to be the case but I may be wrong. I think the title mentioning V-C-V-C was just an example to clarify what they meant by consecutive matches. Anyhow, the question has changed at this point to find the maximum length so *shrug*

Answer (score 2):

If you map consonantal digraphs into single consonants, the longest such word is *anatomicopathological* as a 10*VC string.

If you correctly map **y**, then you get complete strings like *acetylacetonates* as 8*VC and *hypocotyledonary* as 8*CV.

If you don’t need the string to be whole, you get a 9*CV pattern in *chemicomineralogical* and a 9*VC pattern in *overimaginativeness*.

There are many 10* words if runs of consecutive consonants or vowels are allowed to alternate, as in `(C+V+)+`. These include *laparocolpohysterotomy* and *ureterocystanastomosis*.

The main trick is to first map all consonants to C and all vowels to V, then do a VC or CV match. For Y, you have to do lookaheads and/or lookbehinds to determine whether it maps to C or V in that position.

I **could** show you the patterns I used, but you probably won’t be pleased with me. :) For example:

```
 (?<= \p{IsVowel} )     [yY] (?= \p{IsVowel} )  # counts as a C
 (?<= \p{IsConsonant} ) [yY]                    # counts as a V
                        [yY] (?= \p{IsVowel} )  # counts as a C
```

The main trick then becomes one of looking for overlapping matches of VC or CV alternations via

```
 (?= ( (?:  \p{IsVowel}       \p{IsConsonant} )  )+ ) )
```

and

```
 (?= ( (?:  \p{IsConsonant}   \p{IsVowel}     )  )+ ) )
```

Then you count all those up and see which ones are the longest.

However, since Python support doesn’t (by default/directly) support properties in regexes the way I just used them for my own program, this makes it even more important to first preprocess the string into nothing but *C*’s and *V*’s. Otherwise your patterns look really ugly.